# How to expand the arithmetics of differential operators in mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

For example, I want mma to expand out the following differential operator

```
(1+d/dx+x*d2/dy2)^2*(1+y*d/dy)^2
```

I found Nest is not good enough to do this sort of things.

Comment: Sorry ... what is **d2/dy2** ?

Comment: @belisarius: It is the second partial derivative with respect to y.

Comment: @belisarius, @Simon: I am wondering if you know the answer to this very simple question: `D[f[x, y], x] /. {f[x, y] -> x*y}` why here the substitution is not working? Thanks!

Comment: @ Qiang Li Have a look at the `FullForm` of the derivative. But, why don't you make this a new question.

Comment: @Leonid: because i thought it was too simple. I still cannot get it to work after looking at FullForm. I thought of `D[f[x, y], x] /. {f -> x*y}`

Comment: @Qiang Li I do know the answer, but wouldn't encourage this exchange further within comments. Please formulate a new question, with a problem and everything you'd like to get at the end, and somebody will answer. Thanks.

Comment: @Leonid: all right. I posted a new question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4975136/how-to-do-substitution-of-a-function-in-mathematica

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bit dated, but see

http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Conferences/325/

The section "Some noncommutative algebraic manipulation" gives a few ways to go about this.
The first example, defining a function called differentialOperate, is probably best suited for your purposes.

---edit, reedited---

Here is the code I use. Probably it is (still) missing a few refinements. It is taken from a couple of examples in the notebook mentioned above.

I will define and use an auxiliary predicate, scalarQ. This gives the flexibility of declaring entities other than explicit numerical values to be scalar.

I define a noncommutative multiplication, called ncTimes. Ideally I would just use NonCommutativeMultiply, but Iwas not able to get the pattern matching to behave the way I wanted with respect to zero or one argument forms, or pulling out scalars. (Less technical explanation: it's mojo was more powerful than mine.)

scalarQ[a_?NumericQ] := True
scalarQ[_] := False

ncTimes[] := 1
ncTimes[a_] := a
ncTimes[a_**, ncTimes[b_, c**], d_**] := ncTimes[a, b, c, d]
ncTimes[a_**, x_ + y_, b_**] := ncTimes[a, x, b] + ncTimes[a, y, b]
ncTimes[a_**, i_?scalarQ*c_, b_**] := i*ncTimes[a, c, b]
ncTimes[a_**, i_?scalarQ, b___] := i*ncTimes[a, b]

differentialOperate[a_, expr_] /; FreeQ[a, D] := a*expr
differentialOperate[L1_ + L2_, expr_] := 
 differentialOperate[L1, expr] + differentialOperate[L2, expr]
differentialOperate[a_*L_, expr_] /; FreeQ[a, D] := 
 a*differentialOperate[L, expr]
differentialOperate[a : HoldPattern[D[**] &], expr_] := a[expr]
differentialOperate[ncTimes[L1**, L2_], expr_] := 
 Expand[differentialOperate[L1, differentialOperate[L2, expr]]]
differentialOperate[L1_^n_Integer, expr_] /; n > 1 := 
 Nest[Expand[differentialOperate[L1, #]] &, expr, n]

In[15]:= ddvar[x_, n_: 1] := D[#, {x, n}] &

Here are some of your examples, both from post and comments.

In[17]:= diffop = 
 ncTimes[(1 + ddvar[x] + ncTimes[x, ddvar[y, 2]])^2, (1 + 
     ncTimes[y, ddvar[y]])^2]

Out[17]= ncTimes[(1 + (D[#1, {x, 1}] & ) + 
    ncTimes[x, D[#1, {y, 2}] & ])^2, 
   (1 + ncTimes[y, D[#1, {y, 1}] & ])^2]

Apply this operator to f[x,y].

In[25]:= differentialOperate[diffop, f[x, y]]

Out[25]= f[x, y] + 3*y*Derivative[0, 1][f][x, y] + 
 9*Derivative[0, 2][f][x, y] + 
   18*x*Derivative[0, 2][f][x, y] + y^2*Derivative[0, 2][f][x, y] + 
   7*y*Derivative[0, 3][f][x, y] + 14*x*y*Derivative[0, 3][f][x, y] + 
   25*x^2*Derivative[0, 4][f][x, y] + y^2*Derivative[0, 4][f][x, y] + 
   2*x*y^2*Derivative[0, 4][f][x, y] + 
 11*x^2*y*Derivative[0, 5][f][x, y] + 
   x^2*y^2*Derivative[0, 6][f][x, y] + 2*Derivative[1, 0][f][x, y] + 
   6*y*Derivative[1, 1][f][x, y] + 18*x*Derivative[1, 2][f][x, y] + 
   2*y^2*Derivative[1, 2][f][x, y] + 
 14*x*y*Derivative[1, 3][f][x, y] + 
   2*x*y^2*Derivative[1, 4][f][x, y] + Derivative[2, 0][f][x, y] + 
   3*y*Derivative[2, 1][f][x, y] + y^2*Derivative[2, 2][f][x, y]

Those edge cases.

In[26]:= differentialOperate[ncTimes[1, 1], f[t]]

Out[26]= f[t]

We can declare a symbol to be scalar.

In[28]:= scalarQ[a] ^= True;

Now it will get pulled out as a simple multiplier.

In[29]:= differentialOperate[ncTimes[a, b], f[t]]

Out[29]= a b f[t]

---end edit---

Daniel Lichtblau
Wolfram Research

Comment: @Daniel Usually is better to paste the crucial content with proper attribution. That way, if the referred link comes down, some knowledge is preserved here. The copyright restrictions usually don't get affected by a couple of attributed lines.

Comment: @Belisarius I beliee that link has remained intact since the conference in 1998. There is no problem with attribution or copyright (the author is unconcerned...). But yes, I'll post the code with application to the poster's example, when I get a chance. Today, I hope.

Comment: @Daniel, your `differentialOperate` does not work in the simplest case `differentialOperate[1 ** 1, f[t]]`. What if I want to define this in the most non-disruptive way?

Comment: @Daniel, yes, I got it from your link posted earlier. thanks again. The question I am asking is: usually when we have two product we can write `differentialOperate[f**g, f[x,y]]`. But in the degenerate case, I just have two numbers `a**b`, and I should get a*b*f[x,y] as my result. Is there any other more elegant way to do this, except the substitution method I could come up with? i.e. i just `a_ ** b_ -> a*b` after the evaluation of differentialOperate

Comment: @Qiang Li Yes you can do as you indicate. Or see revised edit in response, for more general approach.

Comment: @Qiang Li Now let me ask a question. What I have shown is not technically how to expand the operator, but rather how to make it usable as an actual operator. Is this actually what was wanted, or do you still need expansion? Some tactics for this latter are in the referenced notebook, but they are a bit different than above. For one, they require commutator relations to be defined.