# How to do substitution of a function in mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I have the expression `D[f[x, y], x]`, and I want to substitute `f[x,y]` with `x*y`, I tried the following:

`D[f[x, y], x] /. {f[x,y] -> x*y}`
and
`D[f[x, y], x] /. {f -> x*y}`

But neither worked. Would appreciate your help! Thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `FullForm` of the derivative in your expression is

```
In[145]:= D[f[x,y],x]//FullForm

Out[145]//FullForm= Derivative[1,0][f][x,y]
```

This should explain why the first rule failed - there is no `f[x,y]` in your expression any more. The second rule failed because `Derivative` considers `f` to be a function, while you substitute it by an expression. What you can do is:

```
In[146]:= D[f[x,y],x]/.f->(#1*#2&)

Out[146]= y
```

Note that the parentheses around a pure function are essential, to avoid precedence - related bugs.

Alternatively, you could define your r.h.s through patterns:

```
In[148]:= 
fn[x_,y_]:=x*y;
D[f[x,y],x]/.f->fn

Out[149]= y
```

HTH

Comment: great, thanks. Initially, I did not understand the FullForm fully. :)

Comment: what does HTH mean? I saw this several times already, but never got its meaning.

Comment: Lenoid's answer is correct. Slightly more generally, `D[f[x,y],x]/.f->Times` will work for any number of arguments to f.

Answer (score 8):

Nothing new, just the way I usually think of it:

```
D[f[x, y], x] /. f -> Function[{x, y}, x y]
```

Out

```
y
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also try Hold and Release or Defer etc.

```
Hold@D[f[x, y], x] /. {f[x, y] -> x*y}

D[x y, x]    


Hold@D[f[x, y], x] /. {f[x, y] -> x*y} // Release

y
```