# Mathematica: subscript simplification under noncommutative multiplication

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Using Subscript[variable, integer] in Mathematica 7.0+,  I have expressions of the following form:

```
a_-4 ** b_1 ** a_-4 ** b_-4 ** a_1 ** c_-4 ** c_1 ** c_5
```

I would like to simplify this expression.

Rules:
* Variables with the same subscript to don't commute,
* variables with different subscripts do commute.

I need a way to simplify the expression and combine like terms (if possible); the output should be something like:

```
(a_-4)^2 ** b_-4 ** c_-4 ** b_1 ** a_1 ** c_1 ** c_5
```

The most important thing I need is to order the terms in the expression by subscripts while preserving the rules about what commutes and what does not.  The second thing (I would like) to do is to combine like terms once the order is correct.  I need to at least order expressions like above in the following way:

```
a_-4 ** a_-4 ** b_-4 ** c_-4 ** b_1 ** a_1 ** c_1 ** c_5,
```

that is, commute variables with different subscripts while preserving the non-communicative nature of variables with the same subscripts.

All ideas are welcome, thanks.

Comment: Do you know the commutation properties of objects with the same subscript? If not, then you won't get a unique form for the expressions - and combining them will be suboptimal.

Answer (score 3):

I cited a library notebook the other day for a related question.

http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Conferences/325/

[How to expand the arithematics of differential operators in mathematica](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4974251/how-to-expand-the-arithematics-of-differential-operators-in-mathematica)

I'll crib some relevant code. I first mention (again) that I'm going to define and work with my own noncommutative operator, to avoid pattern matching headaches from built-in NonCommutativeMultiply. Also I will use a[...] instead of Subscript[a,...] for ease of ascii notation and cut-paste of Mathematica input/output.

We will classify certain "basic" entities as scalars or variables, the latter being the things that have commutation restrictions. I am not taking this nearly as far as one might go, and am only defining scalars to be fairly obvious "non-variables".

```
variableQ[x_] := MemberQ[{a, b, c, d}, Head[x]]
scalarQ[x_?NumericQ] := True
scalarQ[x_[a_]^n_. /; !variableQ[x[a]]] := True
scalarQ[_] := False

ncTimes[] := 1
ncTimes[a_] := a
ncTimes[a___, ncTimes[b___, c___], d___] := ncTimes[a, b, c, d]
ncTimes[a___, x_ + y_, b___] := ncTimes[a, x, b] + ncTimes[a, y, b]
ncTimes[a___, n_?scalarQ*c_, b___] := n*ncTimes[a, c, b]
ncTimes[a___, n_?scalarQ, b___] := n*ncTimes[a, b]
ncTimes[a___, x_[i_Integer]^m_., x_[i_]^n_., b___] /; 
  variableQ[x[i]] := ncTimes[a, x[i]^(m + n), b]
ncTimes[a___, x_[i_Integer]^m_., y_[j_Integer]^n_., b___] /; 
  variableQ[x[i]] && ! OrderedQ[{x, y}] := (* !!! *)
    ncTimes[a, y[j]^n, x[i]^m, b]
```

I'll use your input form only slightly modified, so we'll convert ** expressions to use ncTimes instead.

```
Unprotect[NonCommutativeMultiply];
NonCommutativeMultiply[a___] := ncTimes[a]
```

Here is your example.

```
In[124]:= 
    a[-4] ** b[1] ** a[-4] ** b[-4] ** a[1] ** c[-4] ** c[1] ** c[5]

Out[124]= ncTimes[a[-4]^2, a[1], b[1], b[-4], c[-4], c[1], c[5]]
```

An advantage to this seemingly laborious method is you can readily define commutators. For example, we already have (implicitly) applied this one in formulating the rules above.

```
commutator[x_[a_], y_[b_]] /; x =!= y || !VariableQ[x[a] := 0
```

In general if you have commutator rules such as

```
ncTimes[a[j],a[i]] == ncTimes[a[i],a[i]]+(j-i)*a[i]
```

whenever j > i, then you could canonicalize, say by putting a[i] before a[j] in all expressions. For this you would need to modify the rule marked (*!!!*) to account for such commutators.

I should add that I have not in any sense fully tested the above code.

Daniel Lichtblau
Wolfram Research

Answer (score 2):

Is this the type of thing you are looking for

[image: Sort]

These types of rules can be generalised (e.g. add commutation rules for noncommuting objects, make it handle nonnumeric indices, etc...) and packaged up into a `NCMSort` routine. You can also optimize it by doing the sorting in a single pass by defining a unique `NCMOrder` function, e.g.

```
NCMSort[expr_] := expr /. a_NonCommutativeMultiply :> a[[NCMOrder[a]]]
```

---

An aside:
I used such a process in generating the results of [arXiv:1009.3298](http://arxiv.org/abs/1009.3298) -- the notebook will be distributed with the (soon to be released) longer paper.

Comment: I'm tempted to think you planted the question :)

Comment: @Janus Maybe I did... (it's all part of my 5-step get rich plan)

Comment: @Janus : That one was a wicked comment. I'd _never_ suspect such a dirty thing from @Simon. @Simon: Do you need a partner? :D

Answer (score 1):

You can do what you want using [NCAlgebra](https://github.com/NCAlgebra/NC). In the case of your example:

```
<< NC`
<< NCAlgebra`
expr = Subscript[a, -4] ** Subscript[b, 1] ** Subscript[a, -4] ** Subscript[b, -4] ** Subscript[a, 1] ** Subscript[c, -4] ** Subscript[c, 1] ** Subscript[c, 5]
rule = {(Subscript[x_, i_] ** Subscript[y_, j_] /; i > j) -> Subscript[y, j] ** Subscript[x, i]}NCReplaceRepeated[expr, rule]
NCReplaceRepeated[expr, rule]
```

produces

```
Subscript[a, -4] ** Subscript[a, -4] ** Subscript[b, -4] ** Subscript[c, -4] ** Subscript[b, 1] ** Subscript[a, 1] ** Subscript[c, 1] ** Subscript[c, 5]
```

It does not look so nice here but `Subscripts` will render nicely on a Notebook.