# Noncommutative Expand over addition in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I need to write a function(s) that completely expands noncommutative multiplication over addition?
For example:
a ** (b + c^2)
would expand to
a ** b + a ** c^2
and similarly from the right.

I am using ReplaceRepeated (.//). Since I am using NonCommutativeMultiply instead of Times, Expand does not work. I was using the NCAlgebra package which has NCExpand, however ReplaceRepeated does not work when using this package (as stated in the NCAlgebra documentation...argh).

To avoid breaking ReplaceRepeated , I need to code my own NCExpand that is not going to conflict.

All ideas are welcome, thanks...

Comment: Try modifying/using the rules given in [Daniel's answer to your last question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4988323/mathematica-subscript-simplification-under-noncommunative-multiplication/4998375#4998375). If you want to use them in rules instead of `UpValues` you basically just replace the `:=`s with `:>`s.

Comment: Note that you can package the sorting from your previous question similarly to Timo's answer: `NCSort[a_] := a //. rules`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [this](http://www.physics.ohio-state.edu/~jeremy/mathematica/grassmannOps/) package which includes a noncommutative Expand as well as other functions rewritten for NC calculations.

From that package:

```
GExpand[a_, patt___] := Expand[a //. {x_NonCommutativeMultiply :> Distribute[x]}, patt];

In[1]  := GExpand[a ** (b + c^2)]
Out[1] := a ** b + a ** c^2

In[2]  := GExpand[a ** (b + c^2)] //. a -> foo
Out[2] := foo ** b + foo ** c^2
```

Comment: @Timo There are a few nice packages in there too. Thanks for the link!. Do you care to edit the **Mathematica tool bag** question with this link?

Comment: @belisarius, Done. I hadn't added it to the list previously since, frankly, there are inherent problems with Mathematica that make the package not perfect (one should really use FORM for stuff like this). But you're right that there are a lot of goodies in there.

Comment: @Timo,  Thanks, that seems to do the job.  I will test it and post back.

Comment: @Timo: Have you used FORM? I tried earlier last year - but couldn't justify the time spent learning it in order to get the results that I could obtain (computationally more slowly) in Mathematica...

Comment: @Simon: once a long time ago. Like you, I just accept mma's slowness in lieu of spending time switching languages. It is not that hard to learn, especially when there are existing packages that apply to your problem and you don't have to spend time writing all the algebraic rules.

Comment: @Cantormath: Have you had time to test my suggestion? If it didn't work, or you still need help with this problem I'll gladly help.

Answer (score 0):

The newest version of [NCAlgebra](https://github.com/NCAlgebra/NC) supports `ReplaceRepeated` through `NCReplaceRepeated`.