# Redefine Noncommutative Multiplication in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Mathematicas NonCommutativeMultiply (**) does not simplify terms like

```
a**0=0**a=0  
a**1=1**a=a
```

or

```
a**a=a^2.
```

I would like to redefine `**` to do this.  I was using NCAlgebra to do this but I need ReplaceRepeated (//.) and NCAlgebra, as their documentation says, specifically breaks this functionality in mathematica.

Can some show me how to Clear the attributes of `**` and redefine this multiplication do the same things it would normal do plus dealing with 1 and 0.  I really do not need the multiplication to deal with `a**a`, but It would be nice if it is simple enough.  The main thing I need `**` to deal with 1 and 0.

Comment: note that "\*" is used as a [markup metacharacter](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) on SO. You can have a literal "\*" by escaping it with a backslash ("\") or (if appropriate) by marking text as code using a backtick ("\`") for inline code or indenting lines with four spaces. If you click the "edit" link for your question, you can examine the question source to see how it's done. You can read more about the markup language (called Markdown) by clicking the orange question-mark in the editor toolbar.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**The below only works if you remove the Flat attribute of NonCommutativeMultiply**
(Which is something I did by mistake during testing... a rookie mistake!)

The simplest thing to do is

```
Unprotect[NonCommutativeMultiply];
NonCommutativeMultiply[a___, 1, b___] := a ** b
NonCommutativeMultiply[___, 0, ___] := 0
NonCommutativeMultiply[a_] := a
Protect[NonCommutativeMultiply];
```

The final expression is needed so that `a**1` simplifies to `a` instead of `NonCommutativeMultiply[a]`.  You might also need `NonCommutativeMultiply[]:=1` so that expressions like `1**1` simplify properly (*).
The only problem with all of this, is for large expressions, the pattern is checked against everything and this gets really slow.

The above two definitions for 0 and 1 can be combined and generalized to

```
NonCommutativeMultiply[a___, n_?NumericQ, b___] := n a ** b
```

which factors out any numerical terms inside the expression.
But this slows down things even more in large expressions, since each term is checked to see if its numerical.

To simplify your `a**a` to `a^2`, you need something like

```
NonCommutativeMultiply[a___, b_, b_, c___] := a ** b^2 ** c
```

or more generally

```
NonCommutativeMultiply[a___, b_^n_., b_^m_., c___] := a ** b^(n + m) ** c
```

---

(*) Note that this is only because the default order that Mathematica puts its `DownValues` in is not necessarily the best in this case. Change the order so that `NonCommutativeMultiply[a_]` comes before `a___ ** n_?NumericQ ** b___` then `NonCommutativeMultiply[]` won't be generated by the rules, and you won't need that last pattern (unless you produce `NonCommutativeMultiply[]` some other way).

Comment: By the way: My paper and notebook are now [on the arXiv](http://arxiv.org/abs/1102.3043). Because I had really large expressions, you'll see that I had to make tough decisions on how to simplify `NonCommutativeMultiply` expressions. Even then, I had to hold mma's hand for some calculations, otherwise they never terminate.

Comment: @Simon, Optimization is definitely a concern for me as well.  I wonder, if all I need to do is add 0 and 1 to **, how much slower it will be.  Thanks for all your help, I will check the paper now.  I will also try this code out and report back with any issues.

Comment: @Simon, I tried the definition you have above and it returns "$IterationLimit::itlim: Iteration limit of 4096 exceeded. >>" and the output is Hold[1 ** 1 ** 1 **....** 1 ** 1].

Comment: @Cantormath: Damn... I had accidentally run a `ClearAll[NonCommutativeMultiply]` which removed the Flat and OneIdentity attributes. The interplay of my rules with the Flat attribute caused the problems...

Comment: @Cantormath: The problem is you want the greedy pattern matching that the `___**n**___` construction gives you, so that you can move terms outside NonCommutativeMultiply in a *single* step.

Comment: @Simon, the ClearAll[NonCommutativeMultiply] seems to work.  Thank you.  I will keep testing.  My NonCommutativeMultiplication is associative, any suggestions?  Can I add that to the current definition?

Comment: @Cantormath `ClearAll` clears all `Attributes`. The attribute `Flat` is equivalent to associativity. You should read the docs on `Flat` and `OneIdentity` to understand why the code I supplied in this answer is not so good (sorry). This [answer by Daniel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4988323/mathematica-subscript-simplification-under-noncommutative-multiplication/4998375#4998375) shows you how to reinstate associativity - if you want to go that path.

Comment: @ Simon,  WOW, thanks.  I am going to spend sometime working through this, and the next answer you posted, testing etc...  It occured to me after your last post that Flat was the issue I was missing for associative multiplication.  Thank you again...

Answer (score 1):

OK, writing rules that play nice with the attributes of `NonCommutativeMultiply` is sometimes a hassle.  Here's an alternate method which introduces a helper `NCM` that does not have the rules and attributes of `NonCommutativeMultiply` associated with it.

The following code also incorporates the last couple of your questions.
[(1)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4988323/421225) [(2)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5001368/421225)

```
Unprotect[NonCommutativeMultiply];
Clear[NonCommutativeMultiply]
(* Factor out numerics -- could generalize to some ScalarQ *)
nc:NonCommutativeMultiply[a__]/;MemberQ[{a},_?NumericQ]:=NCMFactorNumericQ[NCM[a]]/.NCM->NonCommutativeMultiply
(* Simplify Powers *)
b___**a_^n_.**a_^m_.**c___:=NCM[b,a^(n+m),c]/.NCM->NonCommutativeMultiply
(* Expand Brackets *)
nc:NonCommutativeMultiply[a___,b_Plus,c___]:=Distribute[NCM[a,b,c]]/.NCM->NonCommutativeMultiply
(* Sort Subscripts *)
c___**Subscript[a_, i_]**Subscript[b_, j_]**d___/;i>j:=c**Subscript[b, j]**Subscript[a, i]**d
Protect[NonCommutativeMultiply];

Unprotect[NCM];
Clear[NCM]
NCMFactorNumericQ[nc_NCM]:=With[{pos=Position[nc,_?NumericQ,1]},Times@@Extract[nc,pos]  Delete[nc,pos]]
NCM[a_]:=a
NCM[]:=1
Protect[NCM];
```

Note that `NCMFactorNumericQ` is fast because it works in a single pass, but the rule associated with it `nc:NonCommutativeMultiply[a__]/;MemberQ[{a},_?NumericQ]` is slow, because the Flat attribute means that it does a stupid number of checks using `NumericQ`.
If you really want more speed and have large expressions, then you should just manually apply the `Sort` and `Factor` routines, so that Mathematica does less pattern checks.

Comment: @Simon, So I think I have a definition for multiplication that I like.  I did not use (* Simplify Powers *) and (* Expand Brackets *), I will apply them later.  Something I notice about (* Simplify Powers *), if you say multiply identical expressions that are the sum of many terms together using **, it squares (^2) the expression instead of multiplying it out with noncommutative multiplication.  Again this is not a problem since I am not using it.  An issue I am running into is negative variables at the beginning of an expression.  I am getting `c+(-q)**a` instead of `c-q**a`.

Comment: @Simon, So I think I have a definition for multiplication that I like. I did not use `(Simplify Powers )` and `(Expand Brackets )`, I will apply them later. Something I notice about `(Simplify Powers )`, if you say multiply identical expressions that are the sum of many terms together using `**`, it squares `(^2)` the expression instead of multiplying it out with `**`. Again this is not a problem since I am not using it. An issue I am running into is negative variables at the beginning of an expression. I am getting `b**c+(-q)**a` instead of say `b**c-q**a`.

Comment: @Cantormath: The power problem comes from the `Flat` attribute of `**`. I didn't use such a rule in my work, and an not sure how to get around it. Maybe just manually apply that type of simplification at the end of the evaluation.

Comment: @Cantormath: As for the -'ve thing, maybe something like `NonCommutativeMultiply[a___, b_Times, c___] := 
 NCMFactorNumericQ[NCM[a, Sequence@@b, c]] /. 
  NCM -> NonCommutativeMultiply` will fix it... of course, this will have a performance penalty. Maybe if you include the check as part of the first rule given in the answer...

Comment: @Cantormath: btw the rule I used in my work was `NonCommutativeMultiply/:a_.**((b:numPat) HoldPattern[c_:Sequence[]])**d_.:= b a**c**d` where `Default[NonCommutativeMultiply] = Sequence[];` and `numPat = (_Integer|_Rational|_Real|_Complex)`

Comment: @Simon, I am thinking I will ask this as a new question.  I do not think it is against the rules.

Comment: @Simon, I have posted this new question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5038338/noncommutative-multiplication-and-negative-coeffcients-at-the-beginning-of-an-exp).

Answer (score 1):

The trick with

```
Unprotect[NonCommutativeMultiply];
....
Protect[NonCommutativeMultiply];
```

is very good! I spent 10 hours trying to solve a problem with `NonCommutativeMultiply` (how to flatten expressions that involved both n.c. and normal multiplication like `a**b**(c*d*(e**f))` but more complicated) but I didn't think of amending `NonCommutativeMultiply` itself. Thanks!