# Noncommutative Multiplication and Negative coeffcients at the Beginning of an Expression in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

With the help of some very gracious stackoverflow contributors [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5023863/redefine-noncommutative-multiplication-in-mathematica), I have the following new definition for `NonCommutativeMultiply (**)` in Mathematica:

`Unprotect[NonCommutativeMultiply];

ClearAll[NonCommutativeMultiply]

NonCommutativeMultiply[] := 1

NonCommutativeMultiply[___, 0, ___] := 0

NonCommutativeMultiply[a___, 1, b___] := a ** b

NonCommutativeMultiply[a___, i_Integer, b___] := i*a ** b

NonCommutativeMultiply[a_] := a

c___ ** Subscript[a_, i_] ** Subscript[b_, j_] ** d___ /; i > j :=

 c ** Subscript[b, j] ** Subscript[a, i] ** d

SetAttributes[NonCommutativeMultiply, {OneIdentity, Flat}]

Protect[NonCommutativeMultiply];`

This multiplication is great, however, it does not deal with negative values at the beginning of an expression, i.e.,
`a**b**c + (-q)**c**a`
should simplify to
`a**b**c - q**c**a`
and it will not.

In my multiplication, the variable `q` (and any integer scaler) is commutative; I am still trying to write a `SetCommutative` function, without success.  I am not in desperate need of `SetCommutative`, it would just be nice.

It would also be helpful if I were able to pull all of the `q's` to the beginning of each expression, i.e.,:
`a**b**c + a**b**q**c**a`
should simplify to:
`a**b**c + q**a**b**c**a`
and similarly, combining these two issues:
`a**b**c + a**c**(-q)**b`
should simplify to:
`a**b**c - q**a**c**b`

At the current time, I would like to figure out how to deal with these negative variables at the beginning of an expression and how to pull the `q's` and `(-q)'s` to the front as above.  I have tried to deal with the two issues mentioned here using `ReplaceRepeated (\\.)`, but so far I have had no success.

All ideas are welcome, thanks...

Comment: For the SetCommutative part I suggest you have a look at the grassmanOps package I mentioned in an earlier question. There they have operations to define variables as "fermionic" (anti commuting) and "bosonic" (commuting) and have a modification to NonCommutativeMultiply that checks this grading and takes all bosonic variables out in front.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The key to doing this is to realize that Mathematica represents `a-b` as `a+((-1)*b)`, as you can see from

```
In[1]= FullForm[a-b]
Out[2]= Plus[a,Times[-1,b]]
```

For the first part of your question, all you have to do is add this rule:

```
NonCommutativeMultiply[Times[-1, a_], b__] := - a ** b
```

or you can even catch the sign from any position:

```
NonCommutativeMultiply[a___, Times[-1, b_], c___] := - a ** b ** c
```

**Update -- part 2.** The general problem with getting scalars to front is that the pattern `_Integer` in your current rule will only spot things that are manifestly integers. It wont even spot that `q` is an integer in a construction like `Assuming[{Element[q, Integers]}, a**q**b]`.
To achieve this, you need to examine assumptions, a process that is probably to expensive to be put in the global transformation table. Instead I would write a transformation function that I could apply manually (and maybe remove the current rule form the global table). Something like this might work:

```
NCMScalarReduce[e_] := e //.  {
    NonCommutativeMultiply[a___, i_ /; Simplify@Element[i, Reals],b___] 
    :> i a ** b
}
```

The rule used above uses `Simplify` to explicitly query assumptions, which you can set globally by assigning to `$Assumptions` or locally by using `Assuming`:

```
Assuming[{q \[Element] Reals},
  NCMScalarReduce[c ** (-q) ** c]]
```

returns `-q c**c`.

HTH

Answer (score 2):

Just a quick answer that repeats some of the comments from the previous question.
You can remove a couple of the definitions and solve all of the parts of this question using the rule that acts on `Times[i,c]` where `i` is commutative and `c` has the default of `Sequence[]`

```
Unprotect[NonCommutativeMultiply];
ClearAll[NonCommutativeMultiply]
NonCommutativeMultiply[] := 1
NonCommutativeMultiply[a___, (i:(_Integer|q))(c_:Sequence[]), b___] := i a**Switch[c, 1, Unevaluated[Sequence[]], _, c]**b
NonCommutativeMultiply[a_] := a
c___**Subscript[a_, i_]**Subscript[b_, j_] ** d___ /; i > j := c**Subscript[b, j]**Subscript[a, i]**d
SetAttributes[NonCommutativeMultiply, {OneIdentity, Flat}]
Protect[NonCommutativeMultiply];
```

This then works as expected

```
In[]:= a**b**q**(-c)**3**(2 a)**q
Out[]= -6 q^2 a**b**c**a
```

Note that you can generalize `(_Integer|q)` to work on more general commutative objects.